# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space Hadoop Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs, heap-memory

I'm using Hadoop in my application, but just before the program exits I get this error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` I already modified the `mapred-site.xml` and added this property to it

`<property>
    <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx4096m</value>
</property>`

but still the exception appears.
I used this command in terminal: `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize|PermSize|ThreadStackSize'` and this was the result:

```
uintx AdaptivePermSizeWeight                    = 20              {product}           
     intx CompilerThreadStackSize                   = 0               {pd product}        
    uintx ErgoHeapSizeLimit                         = 0               {product}           
    uintx HeapSizePerGCThread                       = 87241520        {product}           
    uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 1054841728      {product}           
    uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold                = 134217728       {product}           
    uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 16877879296     {product}           
    uintx MaxPermSize                               = 174063616       {pd product}        
    uintx PermSize                                  = 21757952        {pd product}        
     intx ThreadStackSize                           = 1024            {pd product}        
     intx VMThreadStackSize                         = 1024            {pd product}        
java version "1.6.0_31"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.3) (6b31-1.13.3-1ubuntu1~0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

If anyone could please advise how to fix this issue please.

Comment: The max heap size appears to be nearly 16 GiB, which is well over the 4GiB limit you set. Perhaps it has something to do with that?

Comment: so you think I should increase the heap size of hadoop to be 16Gb?

Comment: Possibly, but it might be better to track down why it's using so much.

Comment: Generally when you experience a outofmemory exception you have a leak and it is not your computer it is all about your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

You should consider reviewing your code to see what's causing that resource leak. Usually, it's caused by instances where the [GC](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/understanding-java-garbage-collection/) is not able to remove the data from your memory.

Comment: but I think my code is working fine as I'm expecting it to use lots of memory due to large amount of processing,... and my computer has 32GB memory